# Why is $[0,1]$ not homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$?

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

Why is $[0,1]$ not homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$? It seems that the easiest way to show this is to find some inconsistency between the open set structures of the two. It is clear that the two share the same cardinality. Both are compact. Both are normal since they are metric spaces. However, where to find the open set structure that is not shared by the two? Any hint, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is omeomorphic to $B$ through $f$, then $A \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ is omeomorphic to $B \setminus \lbrace f \left( a \right) \rbrace$ through $f$. Then pick $a= \frac{1}{2}$. $\left[ 0,1\right] \setminus \lbrace \frac{1}{2} \rbrace$ is disconnected, while $\left[ 0,1\right] \times \left[ 0,1\right] \setminus \lbrace p \rbrace$ is connected for any $p \in \left[ 0,1\right] \times \left[ 0,1\right]$.

Comment: Question, why [0,1]$\times$ [0,1] - {p} is still connected?

Answer (score 3):

If you remove an *inner* point from $[0,1]$, the resulting space is disconnected. This is clearly false if you remove *any* point from $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

This is a rather rough approach. A much more general one follows from Dimension Theory, or from the [Invariance-of-domain Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). It is stated for open subsets, but I think it is pretty easy to deduce your statement from the statement that $(0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $(0,1) \times (0,1)$.

Comment: if you remove $0$, then $[0,1]$ remains connected :)

Comment: @user126154 :-) Yes, of course we should not remove a point of the boundary.

Comment: @Mike It seems this is false, but cut-points are preserved by *homeomorphisms*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point

Comment: Argh! I was even thinking about the fact that they *weren't* preserved by continuous maps while I wrote that! (A space-filling curve is a good counterexample.) Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

As comments and other questions point out, this case is easily solved by a connectedness argument.

It may be worth to point out that the general proof that $\mathbb R^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$ for $m\neq n$ is not trivial.

There is a nice important result, called the invariance of domain, (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) that states that if a map $f:U\subset \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous and injective, then it is open. This implies that there is no continuous injective map from $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ to $\mathbb R^n$.